# Android downsample bitmap vs different bitmap sizes

Tags: android

I am currently reading up on developing on Android (beginner) through the website and I am wondering if there is a difference between the following two options and what would be the trade offs, that is if I am going in the correct direction.

The following url explains how we can "downsample" the image to fit into a smaller.
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

In another section, it explains how we have different sized bitmaps for different screen of different densities.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

My question is whats the difference if I choose the first approach, to have a very big bitmap and downsample it according to screen density, (perhaps resulting in more computational power, less battery life) and the second approach, to have several bitmaps of different sizes.

Comment: Different sizes take more room on disk.  Downsampling takes memory and computation time, and may result in graphical glitches.  There's pros and cons to each.

Comment: If so, when an app is available for download in the play store, does the whole "project" consisting of the different sized bitmaps for approach 2 mentioned above gets downloaded, or only the relevant folder for the specific screen density gets downloaded and installed?

Comment: The entire thing, because the apk is a signed entity.  Since Play doesn't know your private key, it can't select a subset of files and resign it.